# Protobuf oneof based on a field value

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to write a Protobuf file using proto3 syntax that matches the Typescript types below. Basically I would like the `value` type to be dependent on what the `field` string is. I can deal with extra object nesting hacks if necessary. Is this possible?

```
type UpdateName = {
  field: 'name',
  value: string
}

type UpdateAge = {
  field: 'age',
  value: number
}

type UpdateRequest = {
  fields: Array<UpdateName | UpdateAge>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I should think so:

```
message Update
{
    oneof type {
        string name = 1;
        integer age = 2;
    }
}

message UpdateRequest
{
    repeated Update updates = 3;
}
```

looks about right.